# Multiple ports in content_security_policy in manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I need to listen more than one **port** in my chrome extension.

My  manifest.json **content_security_policy** line is:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost:35729; object-src 'self'",
```

tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to load script from more than one port on a host, you'll want to whitelist each in turn. That is, a `script-src` directive that allowed loading script over HTTPS from both port 443 and 444 on example.com would look like:

```
script-src https://example.com:443 https://example.com:444;
```

There's no shortcut syntax in CSP to allow whitelisting multiple ports with one source expression.